# Custom Scrollspy is not working on my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some code for highlighting the current link of the page. But the issue is that It is not highlighting the sidebar menu link item by using "activem" class. 
 I'm unable to find out the issue where I'm doing wrong. Below is the code :

> **Here is the jquery part of the website:**
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> var scrollLink = $('.scroll');
>
> // Smooth scrolling
> scrollLink.click(function(e) {
>   e.preventDefault();
>   $('body,html').animate({
>     scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top-80
>   }, 1000 );
> });
>
>
> // Active link switching
> $(window).scroll(function() {
>   var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
>
>   scrollLink.each(function() {
>
>     var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20;
>
>     if ( sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation ) {
>       $(this).addClass('activem');
>       $(this).siblings().removeClass('activem');
>     }
>   });
>
> });
>
> });
> ```

And here is the live page where I used this code : [Demo Page](http://www.incredibleindiantours.com/tour/experiential-rajasthan.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guise I got the issue. The last link from the sidebar menu is not associate with any box due to that It cause the problem. Thanks :)